# How to change instance variable when another related instance variable is changed in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, oop

I recently try to code a text based game. I want to change player proficiency when player level up. How should I change my code for this?

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name,_class,_race):
        self.name = name
        self.level = 1
        self.proficiency = (int(self.level/3)+1)*2
        self.inventory = 0
        self.skills = returnSkills()
        self.stats = returnStats()
        self._class = _class
        self._race = _race
        self.exp = 0

    def levelUp(self):
        self.level+=1


newPlayer = Player("Player","Barbarian","Human")

print(newPlayer.level)

for i in range(10):
    print(newPlayer.level)
    print(newPlayer.proficiency)
    newPlayer.levelUp()
```

Comment: You could make `proficiency` a property, so it is calculated from the current level each time it is referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `proficiency` a property, so it is calculated from the current level each time it is referenced.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name,_class,_race):
        self.name = name
        self.level = 1
        self.inventory = 0
        self.skills = returnSkills()
        self.stats = returnStats()
        self._class = _class
        self._race = _race
        self.exp = 0

    @property
    def proficiency(self):
        return (int(self.level/3)+1)*2
    ...
```

or you could leave it as a plain attribute, and recalculate it inside your `levelUp` method.

Comment: function decorators might be a little advanced for someone who is asking this question. in fact, i have been writing python for a few years now and you taught me something new, so thanks! :)

Comment: If you learned something new, you should probably up-vote this answer @ericstevens26101

Answer (score 1):

You can recalculate the `proficiency` attribute directly in the `levelUp()` function. Once you have updated the `level` attribute, that new value of `level` will be used to calculate the new `proficiency`.

```py
    def levelUp(self):
        self.level+=1
        self.proficiency = (int(self.level/3)+1)*2
```